# Finding the transformation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

> Consider a linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3$ satisfying $$T \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 4 \\ 5 \\ 6 \end{pmatrix} 
>  \ \text{and} \ T \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 3 \\ 4 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 5 \\ 6 \\ 7 \end{pmatrix}. 
> $$

The question told me to find $T\begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 4 \\ 5 \end{pmatrix}$ which I did but I am wondering how would I find the transformation  matrix $T$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:It amounts to finding $a,b$ such that: $a\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix} + b\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 3 \\ 4 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 4 \\ 5 \end{pmatrix}$. Or:

$\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 3 \\ 4 \end{pmatrix} - \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix}$. This takes care of the question being asked.

To find $T$, we have to find: $T(e_1), T(e_2), T(e_3)$ by similar way. **For example**:

Find $x,y,z$ such that: $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} = x\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix} + y\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 3 \\ 4 \end{pmatrix} + z\begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 4 \\ 5\end{pmatrix}$

**Note**: As Rebecca J. Stones pointed out that you have insufficient information to determine $T$. You need to know a value of $T$ at another vector (that is *linearly* *independent* with the first two) to complete the solution.

Comment: I already found the transformation of $T(3 4 5)^T$. I was just wondering, in general, how do I find the transformation $T$?

Comment: So I have to find $a,b$ such that $$a\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix} + b\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 3 \\ 4 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: And similary for $T(e_2), T(e_3)$?

Comment: I row reduced and can not find a value for $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Hm, why use $(1,1,1)$ here? Where did it come from?

Comment: I see, so I will have to just play around with $(1,1,1) + (2,3,4) = (1,0,0)$ until I find $a,b$ that will work?

Comment: See my edit to have a "better idea" of how to proceed....

Comment: I see, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Linearity give us
$$T\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}=T\begin{pmatrix}2\\3\\4\end{pmatrix}-T\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\3\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}5\\6\\7\end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix}4\\5\\6\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}$$
Then
$$T\begin{pmatrix}3\\4\\5\end{pmatrix}=T\begin{pmatrix}2\\3\\4\end{pmatrix}+T\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}5\\6\\7\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}6\\7\\8\end{pmatrix}$$
In order to determine $T$ completely we need the image of some basis $\mathcal{B}$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ under $T$.

Answer (score 1):

There is insufficient information to uniquely determine the transformation matrix.  The transformation matrix has $9$ unknowns and we are given only $6$ linear equations.

It's equivalent to solving the underdetermined system of linear equations

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccccccccc|c}
1 & 2 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 5 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 6 \\
2 & 3 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 5 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 6 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 7 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

If we were to attempt to find it (and it would be tedious to do by hand), we would get a parameterized transformation matrix with $3$ parameters.

---

It's also not possible to uniquely find e.g. $T(e_1)$, since
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 3 \\ 4 \end{bmatrix}, \text{ and } \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
are linearly independent, i.e., there are no solutions to $$a\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix}+b\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 3 \\ 4 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: I see. Thank you very much! So it is a tedious process? I attempted trying to use $e_1$ but couldn't figure out a way.